# Xcode 4.2 & Storyboard, how to access data from another class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

I was wondering how I could access data from another class using Xcode 4.2 and Storyboard?
Say for instance how would I access the text of a text field from another class?
Google hasn't helped and the lesson on MyCodeTeacher.com about this is outdated and doesn't work anymore...

Thanks for bearing with me!

-Shredder2794

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Say I have 2 view-controllers, linked to there separate classes. I want to enter some text into a text field on the first view then click a button and go to the second view. I want a label on the second view to automatically be updated with what I entered on the first view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only or best way, but you can create a property in the destination view's .h file and set it to a value before the segue is performed

in the destination view controller's .h file:

```
@interface YourDestinationViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString* _stringToDisplay;
    //...
}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* stringToDisplay;        
    //...
```

and in the presenting view's .m file

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    YourDestinationViewController*viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    viewController.delegate = self;
    viewController.stringToDisplay = @"this is the string";
}
```

Then you can do what you want with the property in whichever of the viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear/etc. methods best suits your purpose in the destination view's .m file

And then to check if it works, in the destination view controller's .m file:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"self.stringToDisplay = %@", self.stringToDisplay);
    ...
    //and if a label was defined as a property already you could set the 
    //label.text value here
}
```

Edit:  Added more code, and made it less generic

Comment: I'm still having problems with this, would you mind elaborating with example code?

Comment: Added more code and made it pass a string so it will look more like what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to Storyboard. There are several ways to do what you are trying to do. You could declare a variable in your AppDelegate (an NSString) and set that in your first class. Then in your second class access the AppDelegate variable and use that to set your label. The code to do this is:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
label.text = appDelegate.myString;
```

Another way to do it (probably the easiest) is to declare an NSString in your second class. Then in your first class, before you push the second view set that string variable. Something like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
vc.myString = @"";
```

The third way to do this is using delegates. This is the most 'complicated' way but is the best. You would create a delegate which gets called when your second view appears. The delegate could then return the value from the first class to you.

You may also be able to use the new completion handler block on the iOS 5 pushViewController: method.

Edit:

Custom init method:

```
- (void)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSString *)bundle string:(NSString *)myString
```

And then when you are pushing the view just class this method and set the string through it.

Comment: I tried the second method and it seems to delete the string when the new view loads. I NSLog the string right before and after sending it and before its fine but after it just says NULL. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shredder2794 Did you declare a property for the string in the header of your second class? (@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString). Did you synthesize it?

Comment: @Shredder2794 Another way to do this would to be to customize the init method in the second class to accept a string (I've added more example code)

Comment: I'm still having problems with this... I'm a noob. Please read the source-code I posted below and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is probably an EXTREMELY stupid question, but do you think it could be because I have ARC enabled and its deleting my string? Thank you SO much for all your help!

Comment: @Shredder2794 It shouldn't be related to ARC. What kind of string are you passing? Is it a URL? (You might need to escape it)

Comment: I'm passing whatever a user enters in a text field. I'm still not sure what the problem is. Here's my project if you want to look it over.   http://www.mediafire.com/?83s88z5d06hhqb5

Comment: @Shredder2794 I took a look at your code but I can't get it to work. Sorry, I can't spend much time on it now but it's a strange issue. This is something I do everyday and I've never had a problem with it. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: I had simillar problem having Libraries class with event on playback stop. I saw class has its delegate and saw defined methods. Wrote my own methods, so i could execute on event in outside class in my viewController.